# How to connect WinSCP through command line not in GUI mode?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, sftp, winscp

Connect WinSCP console through command-line. Run batch file in it. Commands should be included in batch file for connecting with the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A basic batch file for connecting to SFTP server with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) is like:

```
winscp.com /log=c:\writable\path\winscp.log /ini=nul /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com/ -hostkey=""...""" ^
    "some command like put for upload" ^
    "exit"
```

For details, see a guide to [Automating file transfers to SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

For the `-hostkey` switch see [Verifying the host key in script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey).

---

Easier is to have [WinSCP generate a complete transfer script or even batch file for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating):

[image]